# Acumatica - An object Reference is Required or the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: acumatica

hi does anyone encountered this error? everytime I use PXSelect on a foreach loop in which on the other source code does but on my code does not, could anyone identify the cause? the code below is also the the original source code from Acumatica but I only changed the Datamember from PaymentCharges to OtherCharges

```
    [PXOverride]
    public void VoidCheckProc(ARPayment doc)
    {
        foreach (PXResult<ARPaymentChargeTran> paycharge in PXSelect<ARPaymentChargeTran, Where<ARPaymentChargeTran.docType, Equal<Required<ARPayment.docType>>, And<ARPaymentChargeTran.refNbr, Equal<Required<ARPayment.refNbr>>>>>.
            Select(this, doc.DocType, doc.RefNbr))
        {
            ARPaymentChargeTran charge = PXCache<ARPaymentChargeTran>.CreateCopy((ARPaymentChargeTran)paycharge);
            charge.DocType = Document.Current.DocType;
            charge.CuryTranAmt = -1 * charge.CuryTranAmt;
            charge.Released = false;
            charge.CuryInfoID = Document.Current.CuryInfoID;
            charge.CashTranID = null;
            //PaymentCharges.Insert(charge);
            OtherCharges.Insert(charge);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: your "this" is probably a static class

Comment: Please add the (relevant) code as text rather than images, some users are not able to view images for reasons such as workplace policies. Also include why what you researched didn't solve your problem as of yet

Comment: @KarmaEDV, its a object-method, so `this` is ok.

Comment: @PatrikEckebrecht yes, but we do not see if the containing class is static or not in the image

Comment: Can you show the class outline? This code doesn't compile so it is impossible for us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @KarmaEDV, that doesn't matter. `this` would not be outlined as an error in a non-static class. Anyway, the problem here is that `Select` is called on the `PXSelect<>`-type, not its instance. The class has to be non-static, since the compiler would outline the method as instance-member to be erroneous.

Comment: @PatrikEckebrecht you're right I check the **Select** and it's a static-method, now I have to figure out other alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe, you are writing this method in an extension for the base BLC

So instead of using '**this**', use '**this.Base**'

Comment: thanks! I never thought that you could also call the Base blc.

Answer (score 2):

The `Select` method is non-static, as the error message says, but you call it on the `PXSelect<...>`-type. You need to have an instance of that type.

Based on Hybridzz answer, I assume you used the wrong overload of the `Select`-method. Probably your arguments do not have the correct type, so the compiler selects the best fitting overload of the method. In this case, it selects the one accepting only the argument `params object[] o`, which is non-static. A bit misleasing design of the API you use.

Comment: .Select() method of that command requires an instance of PXGraph as the first argument, when you write an extension,it is not inheritined from PXGraph but from PXGraphExtension, so here you can use the this.Base, which is the instance of Base graph as the first parameter.